# How to run a shellscript continuously regardless of result code or message?

Tags: docker, shell, pm2

I wanted to run a server through node pm2, so i made a script like this

**runNode.sh**

```
cd /nodeApp && npm run build && pm2 delete all && pm2 start UI0
cd /
```

But, sometimes it didn't work until the end. When it run `pm2 delete all` then it stopped and showed message '[PM2][WARN] No process found' I guess it's because of invisible
result code during the running `pm2 delete all`.

In the other hand, after when I built a docker, if I commanded tomcat `catalina start` in the middle of the CMD or ENTRYPOINT script, when I run the docker, it didn't last long. It stopped. I guessed it's because of invisible result code after `catalina start`.

Could you please tell me how can I see the result codes, and how can I manipulate the script and run even error occured?

Comment: Tried replacing `&&` with `;` ?

Comment: Oh it worked on runNode.sh well, thx!